# How do I do proximity search in Oracle right?

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search

Oracle's [NEAR operator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm#i997808) for full text search returns a score based on the proximity of two or more query terms. For example:

> near((dog, bite), 6)

matches if 'dog' and 'bite' occurs within 6 words. What if I'd like it to match if either 'dog' or 'cat' or any other type of animal occurs within 6 words of the word 'bite'? I tried:

> near(((dog OR cat OR animal), bite), 6)

but I got:

> NEAR operand not a phrase, equivalence
>   or another NEAR expression

Rather than expanding all possible combination into multiple NEAR and 'or' them together, what is the proper way to write such query?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the EQUIV operator should do it. [Doc Ref](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#CHDFBBEH).

> You can also use the equivalence
>   operator to substitute a single term
>   in a near query:
>
> 'near((stock crash, Japan=Korea), 20)'
>
> This query asks for all documents that
>   contain the phrase stock crash within
>   twenty words of Japan or Korea.

Comment: Thanks, and it seems the equivalence operator even work on more than 2 terms:

'near((stock crash, Japan=Korea=China),20)'

But, how would you 'near' a word with another 'near' clause?